# Unable to install specific version of nodejs in my php-nginx:7.4-alpine docker image

Tags: node.js, docker

So [I've found an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1125969/how-to-install-npm-in-alpine-linux#comment2465481_1424979) on how to install specific version of nodejs.

My dockerfile goes as follows:

```
FROM webdevops/php-nginx:7.4-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html
```

I want to install nodejs, [version 14.18.1](https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v14.x/). So after `FROM` and before `WORKDIR`, I've added:

`RUN apk add --update nodejs=14.18.1`

Then as soon as I rebuild the image I get:

```
[+] Building 2.6s (5/6)
 => [internal] load build definition from app.dockerfile                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 172B                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/webdevops/php-nginx:7.4-alpine                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/webdevops/php-nginx:7.4-alpine                                                                                         0.0s
 => ERROR [2/3] RUN apk add --update nodejs=14.18.1                                                                                                    2.5s
------
 > [2/3] RUN apk add --update nodejs=14.18.1:
#5 0.185 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 1.220 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 1.567 fetch https://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 2.430 ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
#5 2.456   nodejs-12.22.6-r0:
#5 2.456     breaks: world[nodejs=14.18.1]
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apk add --update nodejs=14.18.1]: exit code: 1
```

If I replace this line with `RUN apk add --update nodejs npm` then it works but it installs version 12 which not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 14.18.1 version is not available in alpine 3.12 version, but it is in 3.14. Either use some other version of `webdevops/php-nginx` which will use alpine 3.14, or try to add some alpine registry which has node.js v14.18.1. I don't know how to do this for alpine. Also you could extend your post with output of `cat /etc/os-release` executed in container. Looking at the image's Dockerfile I would say that it uses alpine:3.14, but the `fetch ...` URLs suggest otherwise.